# Tokyo to Bangalore via Thailand on Indian passport

Tags: international-travel, connecting-flights, airasia

I want to take a flight from Tokyo to Bangalore and the cheapest option seems to be one via Thailand by Thai AirAsia X and Thai AirAsia but I am supposed to transfer from the BKK airport to DMK. I have around 5.5 hrs to make this transfer.

Since I am not a frequent traveller, wondering if taking this option is good, and worth the risk.

There are a few blogs where I can see that a shuttle service runs between the two airports for connecting flights, so I am assuming that there is a fair amount of traffic between the two.

Comment: Is that booked as a single ticket? If so the airline presumably thinks you can make the transfer in time. I have no idea what the visa situation would be.

Comment: Remember you'll also have to satisfy whatever covid-related requirements (e.g., vaccination, test, quarantine) Thailand and India may impose.

Comment: For single airport self connections people here claim 4 hours as the minimum. I guess you will need quite a bit more connecting between airports. I would not book it with only  5.5 hours. (But I have never been there and I am not inclined to book self connects anyhow.)

Answer (score 1):

This itenary is highly risky.

Assume everything went fine, this will be the case.

1. Getting out of Airport after procedures - 1 hour
2. Transfer to the DMK airport - 1 hour
3. Checkin and immigration process. - 2 hour (recommended minimum)

So, a small 30 minute delay in any process can throw off the plan (You have to get to the airport within 2 hours of departure). On top of that, you have to take on arrival visa, which will cost 2000 THB (~4500 INR).

So, is it worth it?